# Should "What is an easy vegetable to grow" be made Comm-Wiki?

Tags: discussion, support

A question came up about asking '[easy questions](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/98/40)'; it referred to the [Easy-Veg question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/378/what-is-an-easy-vegetable-to-grow-for-beginners) as an example of this.

It seems to me this question was a poor example for their question (which was likely meant to address questions of a trivial nature).  The Easy-Veg question can be split in two directions, and I would like to know how people are viewing it:

> Should it be left as an objectively answerable, nice and specific question to suit this individuals specific needs (which the OP will need to provide), **OR** converted to [Community Wiki format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/149114) as a standard 'important learning books' CW question?

- In the former case, the question fails spectacularly by being incredibly broad, vague and has no discernible criteria for evaluating any expertise in a given answer.
- In the latter case, it is very list-y, but that doesn't mean it's a failure. Looking at [the stackoverflow democracy, cream-to-the-top example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711) this question pretty much fits the bill.

  - In a more interesting case, it could possible be restructured into an incredible useful list broken out by region/climate or other sort-criteria in line with [cooking.se's list of glossary translations](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/15).

What are your feelings on this question, it should be restructured before it's roots take too strong a hold.

Comment: Wow, I hate that book question. You'd think, after almost three years, I would hate it less... But no, each year that goes by I find it more and more disturbing and wrong.

Comment: @shog I bristled looking for the m.so stuff as well. I know any CW thing is contentious but that's why I thought changing the whole thing might make it useful, a la the cooking translations

Answer (score 6):

I suggest nuking such questions as vague/not-a-real-question.  "Easy to grow" can mean so many different things that it's hard to provide anything but multiple, equally valid, stabs in the dark.

Of course, while voting to close those I would add a friendly comment inviting the OP to edit the question or post a new one that is more specific, for example:

"I'm new to gardening, and a little nervous about putting a lot of effort into plants I may not yet have the skill to care for.  What is a very hardy perennial flower for partial shade next to my house in $geographic-area?"

-or-

"I have too little time to spend gardening these days, so I'm trying to trade in some of my more finicky plants for lower-maintenance ones.  In particular, I have $plant-foo and $plant-bar in my garden, but would like to find varieties that don't require such frequent watering."

-or-

"My daughter wants her first vegetable garden, and I want to help her be a success despite her stereotypically six-year-old attention span.  What five or six veggies could I help her put in that will fare well with minimal intervention after planting?  We live in $climate-zone."

"Easy" can mean "hardy", "needing less $resource" (such as water), "low-maintenance", or any number of other things.  Rather than relegating vague questions to CW status, help them shape up into really great questions like the examples above.

Comment: I agree by virtue of the criticism in my question here ; I just wonder if it might be repurposed as something useful given the amount of energy in answering

Comment: The problem is that the vague question led to answers that are all over the place -- I don't think there's an edit that would improve the question without deprecating all/most of the existing answers.  I'd just let this one go as a learning experience rather than setting a bad precedent for the future.

Answer (score -3):

My opinions are:

1) With the exact description of the weather/soil condition/temperature/etc, we can give many suggestions that is good.

2) With a community wiki, it is essential for editor to have a good knowledge about what he is editing and not getting subjective. Maybe he get a good sunshine/average temperature and most of his/her plant grow pretty good, thus he/she think the plant are easy. Who knows?

3) With a community wiki, it is possible to expand the list into category of different weather/soil condition/temperature and we should decide what is the range of very hot/hot/warm/cool/cold because that is subjective too....who to blame if one don't know his weather is very very hot(maybe 35+ degree Celsius) and he failed to plant a plant with moderate tolarance to hot(maybe 30-34 degree Celsius)?

4) The wiki should be descriptive about the plant too.